# Is this a correct way of using forkJoin and mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I need to make all requests in parallel whenever it's possible. Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
const arr = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3',
];

let observables = [];
for (let url of arr) {
  observables.push(this.http.get(url));
}

const obs$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    //an array of urls like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/5
    let urls = data.data;
    let observables = [];
    for (let url of urls) {
      observables.push(this.http.get(url));
    }
    return observables;
  }),
  mergeMap((data) => forkJoin([...data]))
);

forkJoin([...observables, obs$]).subscribe({
  next: (data) => console.log(data, 'from fork'),
  error:(err)=>console.log(err)
});
```

So, I have in this case:

1. An array of observables `observables`
2. An observable `obs$` that fetches  some urls, and upon fetching the urls, I need to make requests to those urls in parallel as well.

I don't care about results, I only care if something errors out. These example code seems to be working properly, however, I've got a couple of questions since I'm trying to wrap my head around RxJS.

1. Is this a proper way of doing things in order to achieve goals I described above?
2. `mergeMap((data) => forkJoin([...data]))` -> mergeMap here basically only helps me getting an Observable out of the nested Observable, right? So I could technically use concatMap or switchMap with the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need `forkJoin`, you can simply create an observable that emits individual urls, then use `mergeMap` to make the request for that url and emit the results.

Since you have two different url sources, we can define those separately, then just use `merge` to create a single observable from both sources:

```js
const urls_1$: Observable<string> = from(arr);

const urls_2$: Observable<string> = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').pipe(
  mergeMap(response => response.data)
);

const response$ = merge(urls_1$, urls_2$).pipe(
  mergeMap(url => this.http.get(url))
).

response$.subscribe({
  next: data => console.log(data),
  error: err => console.log(err)
});
```

- `urls_1$`: we use `from` to create observable that emits the array elements individually
- `urls_2$`: we make http call then use `mergeMap` to emit the received array elements individually.  This has the same effect as `from` above (*in fact `mergeMap` used `from` internally*).  You are correct, that you could use any of the higher order operators here.
- `responses$`: here we use `merge` to create a single observable from both of our sources.  This means whenever `url_1$` or `url_2$` emit a value, the "merge observable" will emit it.  We then use `mergeMap` to make the http call an emit its result.  Unlike the previous `mergeMap`, this one cannot be substituted by `switchMap` or `concatMap` because you want the requests to be made in parallel. The result here is that our `response$` observable will emit the response of each request.

  - if you wanted to limit the number of concurrent requests, you can provide the second `concurrency` parameter to `mergeMap`:

```js
mergeMap(url => this.http.get(url), 5) // <-- limit to 5 active requests
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your example makes a lot of sense and is much cleaner. Just to clarify: is there anything wrong with the way I implemented things in my example? Or is it more of a weird way of doing things, however, from functional prospective it works the same way?

Comment: In url2, why do you mergemap on something that is apparently not an observable?

Comment: @maxime1992 because the data is a `string[]` and I want to emit the strings one at a time. It's basically like doing `mergeMap(arr => from(arr))`.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't realize it was an array.

Comment: @noob - yeah I think the behavior is basically the same if you don't care about the emissions.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Is this a proper way of doing things in order to achieve the goals I described above?**

Yes. It is.

**2. mergeMap((data) => forkJoin([...data])) -> mergeMap here basically only helps me getting an Observable out of the nested Observable, right? So I could technically use concatMap or switchMap with the same effect?**

Based on what you are trying to achieve using mergeMap is the wisest. Even though concatMap and switchMap have similar effects, they also will add some logic you don't need.

**concatMap:** Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next.

**switchMap:** Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When it comes to the second question, my  understanding is that because `http.get`  only produces one observable and  there is no stream of observables, there would be no difference if I use mergeMap,  concatMap, or switchMap? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I was going to answer this question, but I see @BizzyBob already did.

Answer (score 1):

Off topic, but please note you could rewrite

```
const arr = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3',
];

let observables = [];
for (let url of arr) {
  observables.push(this.http.get(url));
}
```

to

```
const observables = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3',
].map(url => this.http.get(url));
```

You're also shadowing `observables` variable by declaring it twice (once at the beginning, and once inside your map). Please use different names (`observables1` and `observables2` would do the trick).